# Usar WhereRaw com DateDiff

Tags: laravel-eloquent

Preciso pegar a diferença em dias entre a data atual e a data armazenada no banco, subtrair essa diferença por 90 e então verificar se o resultado é igual a 7. Onde está o erro?

```
whereRaw("90 - (DATEDIFF(now(), 'updated_at')) = 7")
```

Comment: Eu fiz uma resposta dá uma olhada acredito que não seja aspas ali, porque é um campo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não seria assim, ou seja, o campo `updated_at` sem aspas, porque é um campo da sua tabela:

```
whereRaw("(90 - (DATEDIFF(now(), updated_at))) = 7")
```